# java tile based game :tile lag fix

Tags: java, tiles, tilemap, lag

hi I have a game where it reads a txt file and loads a map 0 represents air and 2 represents dirt I have a class for each tile as well as a tilemap I will show u my code. the problem is it lags like all hell. is there something I am doing wrong or is there something I need to add like rendering a certain amount of tiles at a time.(I don't know how to do that).it lags really bad. here is my code:

public class tilemap {

```
private int x;
private int y;

private int tilesize;
private static int[][] map;
private int mapwidth;
private int mapheight;
public static Image img;
public static int camx,camy;
public static BufferedImage stone;

public ArrayList<air> air = new ArrayList<air>();
public ArrayList<dirt> dirt = new ArrayList<dirt>();

public String sl;

public tilemap(String s,int tilesize){
    this.tilesize = tilesize;

    try{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));

        mapwidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        mapheight = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        map = new int[mapheight][mapwidth];

        String del = " ";
        for(int row = 0; row < mapheight; row++){
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(del);
            for(int col = 0; col < mapwidth; col++){
                map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){}

    try{
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}


public void update(){
    //checkcollision();
      for (int i = 0; i < air.toArray().length; i++) {
            air.get(i).tick();

        }
      for (int i = 0; i < dirt.toArray().length; i++) {
            dirt.get(i).tick();

        }

}






public void draw(Graphics g){
    for(int row = 0; row < mapheight; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < mapwidth; col++){

             int rc = map[row][col];

             int mr = tilesize*row;
             int mc = tilesize*col;

              if(rc == 0){
                  air.add(new air(mc,mr));
              }
              if(rc == 2){
                  dirt.add(new dirt(mc,mr));
              }

              for (int i = 0; i < air.toArray().length; i++) {
                air.get(i).render(g);

              }


              for (int i = 0; i < dirt.toArray().length; i++) {
                dirt.get(i).render(g);

              }


        }
    }

}
```

}

public class air {

```
public int y;
public int x;
public Image img;

public Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x,y,40,40);

public air(int x,int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
public void tick(){

}

public void render(Graphics g){
     ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/water.png");
        img = i2.getImage();
        g.drawImage(img,x - tilemap.camx,y-tilemap.camy,null);   

}
```

}

public class dirt {

```
public int y;
public int x;
public Image img;

public Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x,y,40,40);

public dirt(int x,int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
public void tick(){

}

public void render(Graphics g){
     ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/dirt.png");
        img = i2.getImage();
        g.drawImage(img,x - tilemap.camx,y-tilemap.camy,null);   

}
```

}

Comment: Use a profiler.

Comment: whats a profiler

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=what+is+a+profiler

Answer (score 2):

You are loading a graphic *for every tile in every frame*. Load it once at application startup that sould improve the speed dramatically.

Comment: how do u suggest I do this

Comment: You could make the image a static field of the class